# Difference between subsequent values in rows with same code: value error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, calculated-columns

I have a DataFrame with 3 columns: POD (which is a code), timestamp, EAI_ALL (number).
I want to calculate a 4th column where every row has the following value: the value of EAI_ALL of the current row minus the value of EAI_ALL on the previous row. This has to be done for every code (e.g. if the current code is 2 and the code in the previous row is 1, the calculated value has to be 0 because the code is different).
I managed to do this operation with the following code:

```
#group the DF by POD code
grouped = df.groupby('POD')


#Define Lambda function
eai_diff = lambda x: x.EAI_ALL - x.EAI_ALL.shift(+1)

df['EAI_Delta'] = grouped.apply(eai_diff).reset_index(0, drop=True).fillna(0)
```

This works fine, unless I have only one POD code in the DataFrame.
I keep getting this error if I apply the function to a DataFrame with only one POD code.

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 48, placement implies 1
```

As you can see df has 48 rows, but with the group by it gets reduced to one row.
I need the groupby because if I have more than one POD code the operation basically has to be done for one POD code at a time.

Does anyone have any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error that comes back regularly, which comes from the fact that returning a series from a dataframe `apply` with a single group returns a dataframe with a single row, and the index as columns:

```
>>> df
   POD  EAI_ALL
0  foo        0
1  foo        1
2  foo        2
3  foo        3
4  foo        4
5  foo        5
6  foo        6
7  foo        7
8  foo        8
>>> df.groupby('POD').apply(lambda x: x.EAI_ALL - x.EAI_ALL.shift(+1))
EAI_ALL   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
POD                                                
foo     NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

To avoid that, and if you really need `.apply`, you can return a dataframe instead:

```
>>> df.groupby('POD').apply(lambda x: x[['EAI_ALL']] - x[['EAI_ALL']].shift(+1))
   EAI_ALL
0      NaN
1      1.0
2      1.0
3      1.0
4      1.0
5      1.0
6      1.0
7      1.0
8      1.0
```

However the better way is to try and stay away from `.apply`. For your use case, [`groupby.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) works perfectly and only shifts within the group as you expect:

```
>>> df.groupby('POD')['EAI_ALL'].shift()
0  NaN
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    5
>>> df['EAI_Delta'] = (df['EAI_ALL'] - df.groupby('POD')['EAI_ALL'].shift()).fillna(0)
>>> df
   POD  EAI_ALL  EAI_Delta
0  foo        0        0.0
1  foo        1        1.0
2  foo        2        1.0
3  foo        3        1.0
4  foo        4        1.0
5  foo        5        1.0
6  foo        6        1.0
7  foo        7        1.0
8  foo        8        1.0
```

And an example with several `POD` values:

```
>>> df2['EAI_Delta'] = (df2['EAI_ALL'] - df2.groupby('POD')['EAI_ALL'].shift()).fillna(0)
>>> df2
   POD  EAI_ALL  EAI_Delta
0  foo        0        0.0
1  foo        1        1.0
2  foo        2        1.0
3  foo        3        1.0
4  bar        4        0.0
5  bar        5        1.0
6  bar        6        1.0
7  bar        7        1.0
8  bar        8        1.0
```

Even better as suggested by @mandiatodos in comments, you can directly use [`.groupby().diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, very helpful!
I actually solved it this way: 
`df['EAI_Delta'] = df.groupby(['POD'])['EAI_ALL'].diff().fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use pandas version less than  `1.1.0` you can set `squeeze` parameter of `groupby` to `True`:

```
import pandas as pd

def group_with_squeeze(df):
    grouped = df.groupby('POD', squeeze=True)
    eai_diff = lambda x: x.EAI_ALL - x.EAI_ALL.shift(+1)
    df['EAI_Delta'] = grouped.apply(eai_diff).reset_index(0, drop=True).fillna(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'POD': list('ABBBCC'), 'EAI_ALL': [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4]})
group_with_squeeze(df)
df
#  POD  EAI_ALL  EAI_Delta
# 0   A        1        0.0
# 1   B        2        0.0
# 2   B        3        1.0
# 3   B        1       -2.0
# 4   C        4        0.0
# 5   C        4        0.0

df = pd.DataFrame({'POD': list('AAAAAA'), 'EAI_ALL': [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4]})
group_with_squeeze(df)
df
#   POD  EAI_ALL  EAI_Delta
# 0   A        1        0.0
# 1   A        2        1.0
# 2   A        3        1.0
# 3   A        1       -2.0
# 4   A        4        3.0
# 5   A        4        0.0
```